# Plupload connection reset error

Tags: javascript, plupload

I installed the Plupload plugin on my website for uploading images, however the upload process sometimes generates an error. When I attempt to upload a lot of files, occasionally one or two images fail to complete the upload and generate the message ERR_CONNECTION_RESET.

Is there anything I can do to stop this error from occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Check your web server. It probably fail on the biggest files. Some kind of limit is reached so the connection is being reset by the server.

Comment: Entirely possible, but when I test by uploading the same images again, either they all work on this attempt, or different images fail to upload.